# Compare for equality two cyrillic strings from sql database and .xls file in PHP

Tags: php, string-comparison

I am using `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` to process .xlss the file.

As the columns order in the file may varry depending on the file sender I have a table in database, where I store the sender name (in cirilic) and the number of columns for the rest of data.

So, before processing the file I need to compare if the sender name from database is the same as the content of a field in the file to get the coresponded columns values and process the file only if name values match.

Despite the fact, that I am 100% sure they are the same, whatever comparison I try return false.

**1. File processing**

```
$allowedFileType = [
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'text/xls',
    'text/xlsx',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
];
    
$targetPath = './tmp/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$error = 0;

//Check if file is already uploaded
if (!empty($importFromFile->getImportedFileName($filename))) {
    setEventMessages($langs->trans('FileExists'), null, 'errors');
    $error++;
}
 
if (!$error) {
    $Reader = new Xlsx();
    $spreadSheet = $Reader->load($targetPath);
    $excelSheet = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet();
    $spreadSheetAry = $excelSheet->toArray();
    $sheetCount = count($spreadSheetAry);

    foreach ($externalsales->getImportSettings() as $obj) {
        $name1 = $obj->ref; //This is the name from the database
        $name_row = $obj->distributor_name_row - 1;
        $name_column = $obj->distributor_name_column - 1;
        $name2 = $spreadSheetAry[$name_row][$name_column]; //this is the name from the file

        //At this point, I need to compare returned names from database to the name in the file
    }
}
```

**2. Compare**

```
print $name1 . ' - ' . $name2;
//returns ДЕЛИВЪРИ ООД - ДЕЛИВЪРИ ООД
//You can see they are same

print strcasecmp($name1, $name2);
print strcasecmp(trim($name1), trim($name2));
print strcasecmp(mb_strtolower($name1), mb_strtolower($name2));
//all 3 return "176"

print strcmp($name1, $name2);
print strcmp(trim($name1), trim($name2));
print strcmp(mb_strtolower($name1), mb_strtolower($name2));
//all 3 return "1"

print strcoll($name1, $name2) . '<br>';
//returns "1"

$coll = collator_create( 'bg_BG' );
$res  = collator_compare( $coll, $name1, $name2 );
print $res;
//returns "1"
```

For the test, I have inserted second record in the database with random name that I am not sure is in the files.

For the first 3 options, the return is `32,32,-176`, for the second 3 is `1,1,-1`, `1` for `strcoll` and `-1` for the collator.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To check what was causing the error, I've used `bin2hex()` for both values. The result showed that there were some white spaces (I presume the `20` stand for space as `%20` in html) in the string coming from the .xls file.

The output was:

```
print bin2hex($name1)
//d094d095d09bd098d092d0aad0a0d09820d09ed09ed094

print bin2hex($name1)
//d094d095d09bd098d092d0aad0a0d0982020d09ed09ed0942020
```

So when I strip those white spaces with `str_replace(' ', '', $name1);` the if condition `if ($name1 === $name2)` returns `true`, which is what I was looking for.

If anyone can explain the reasons for this difference better than me feel free to reply.